# Login page include "sign in with existing account" title, then removed for Azure B2C

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c

We have a login page, but when I try to login firstly middle layout and "sign in with existing account" title occurred. after 1 second my login page showing. I want to remove the layout that displaying first for 1 second.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more details which helps us to repo this issue

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be describing the initial flash, where the client is downloading the custom HTML, therefore the CSS has not loaded. You can use the “preload” HTML tag in your CSS and JS elements to make sure B2C loads those before populating the div api element.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-ui-customization#guidelines-for-using-custom-page-content

Comment: Thank you. You are great. The problem is solved with this solution. :D